# How does Spark resolve system properties in strings (without string interpolation)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I saw the below snippet in [this blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html)

```
val warehouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse"
val spark = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
   .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
   .enableHiveSupport()
   .getOrCreate()
```

How does the system property `user.dir` is substituted in the warehouseLocation value. Shouldn't the string be `s"file:${System.getProperty("user.dir")}/spark-warehouse"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse` is **equal to** `s"file:${System.getProperty("user.dir")}/spark-warehouse"`.

In **Spark**, it has implemented [substitute](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/17ce0b5b3f6a825fc77458bc8608cece1a6019c7/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/config/ConfigReader.scala#L86) by itself, and bind read config from `env`(`System.getEnv`), `system`(`System.getProperty`) **prefix** or **customise** config `provider`.